# How to make the icon of a UWP app on taskbar bigger and transparent?

Tags: uwp

[image]

Above picture is much brief, Windows app are much bigger than mine, and background is transparent.

In Package.appxmanifest, Visual Assets, I generated all using a source.

I'm using visual studio 2017, version 15.9.14.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Light mode, apps that don't support the Light icon are shown with a background color with an icon. It is not difficult to create icons in Light mode. There are two main ways:

**1. Increase the project's TargetVersion to 1903**

After updating the target version, Package.appxmanifest will be updated and you can find it in the visual object asset. (Visual Studio 2019 is recommended. )

**2. Manually create related LightIcon**

If you can't adjust the Target Version or are not satisfied with the converted icon, you can create the Light icon manually.

In your icon folder, look for the file named `Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-256.png`. According to the resolution, there are 5 icons in this series, which are 256, 48, 32, 24, 16 respectively.

You need to create the icon in these 5 resolutions and rename it to `Square44x44Logo.altform-lightunplated_targetsize-[size].png`.

Just put `light` in front of `unplated`.

Once created, you can include the new Icon in your project in Visual Studio.

Best regards.

Comment: I've already targeted to 1903, and generated all assets. They are all transparent background. See the picture in original qustion. But my app on taskbar still have a green(system accent color) background.

Comment: Please check the VS file tree to see if the newly added icons are included in the project. If it is not included in the project, the light icon will not take effect.

Comment: Sure. [Here](https://github.com/Richasy/Light-Icon-UWP) it is. Please note that I was packaged with Visual Studio 2019 and it passed the test. If you still can't build, choose to use Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Hi, I confirmed that vs 2017 does not support light mode. I downloaded 2019, and it works. Thx.